# How to layout extjs fileuploadfield widget

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am using the extjs **fileuploadfield** (xtype).

When I add this to my panel it looks very ordinary :

[image]

The text field should stretch out to the end of the 'File : ' label, and ideally I would want the browse button more to the right. This is how i use it :

```
               layout: {
                    type: 'anchor'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        flex: 1,
                        xtype: 'label',

                        text: 'Upload',
                        style: 'font-weight: bold',
                        height: 22
                    },
                    {
                        flex: 1,
                        xtype: 'radio',
                        boxLabel: 'Client [Pfad / Dateiname]',
                        name: 'radioradio',
                        itemId:'RadioClientUploadWindow',
                        checked: 'true'
                    }, {
                        flex: 1,
                        xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
                        id: 'filedata',
                        emptyText: 'Select a document to upload...',
                        fieldLabel: 'File ',
                        buttonText: 'Browse '
                    },
```

Is there some way of making this component look reasonably OK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oliver,

When designing forms, Sencha had in mind that you would have many fields in your form, so all the labels have the same width to make a consistent look on your screen.

Your form looks weird because you only have one form field there. To adjust your width, just set your `labelWidth` to whatever is proper to your form (I believe 40 would be right for you), also, I don't think the setting `flex` works with the `anchor` layout, try replacing it with `anchor: 100%`.
This should make your field looks better:

```
{
    xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
    anchor: '100%',
    labelWidth: 40,
    id: 'filedata',
    emptyText: 'Select a document to upload...',
    fieldLabel: 'File ',
    buttonText: 'Browse '
}
```